# google endpoint timeout on devserver

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using google-endpoint V2 on app engine standard, with firebase authentication.

When deploying locally, the server starts and runs fine. When a query is issued to access one of the endpointV2, I get an inconsistent behavior:

- it works well for a bit (the endpoint returns with the expected payload), but sometimes gets stuck trying to contact `https://servicecontrol.googleapis.com/v1/services/my-project-id.appspot.com:check`.
- It takes about a minute to timeout, then the next query may timeout or return properly...

Any idea of how to resolve that would be appreciated!

The logs in the devserver, for a failed query:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD:  failed because of java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: https://servicecontrol.googleapis.com/v1/services/my-project-id.appspot.com:check
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 02, 2017 12:27:06 AM com.google.api.control.Client check
[INFO] GCLOUD: SEVERE: direct send of a check request service_name: "my-project-id.appspot.com"
[INFO] GCLOUD: operation {
[INFO] GCLOUD:   operation_id: "7453fb02-56e3-48ec-856c-e25d09ccc792"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   operation_name: "1.recipes_groceries_appspot_com.ApiadminPop"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   consumer_id: "project:my-project-id"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   start_time {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     seconds: 1501658786
[INFO] GCLOUD:     nanos: 76000000
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   end_time {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     seconds: 1501658786
[INFO] GCLOUD:     nanos: 76000000
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   labels {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     key: "servicecontrol.googleapis.com/referer"
[INFO] GCLOUD:     value: "http://localhost:4200/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.4KxLsUEUJCA.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOh765ksalVtUgJb_uys4PUTu6HZA"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   labels {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     key: "servicecontrol.googleapis.com/caller_ip"
[INFO] GCLOUD:     value: "127.0.0.1"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   labels {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     key: "servicecontrol.googleapis.com/user_agent"
[INFO] GCLOUD:     value: "ESP"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD:   labels {
[INFO] GCLOUD:     key: "servicecontrol.googleapis.com/service_agent"
[INFO] GCLOUD:     value: "EF_JAVA/1.0.4"
[INFO] GCLOUD:   }
[INFO] GCLOUD: }
[INFO] GCLOUD:  failed because of java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: https://servicecontrol.googleapis.com/v1/services/my-project-id.appspot.com:check
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 02, 2017 12:27:06 AM com.google.api.control.ControlFilter doFilter
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: the check did not succeed; the response null
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 02, 2017 12:27:06 AM com.google.api.server.spi.auth.GoogleAppEngineAuthenticator authenticate
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: appEngineUser = example@example.com
```

Comment: How frequently would you say this happens?

Comment: The usual pattern is that it does not happen for a couple of minutes after local deployment, and then timeout occurs. After that initial period of a few minutes, it happens frequently. The request timeout, next one will try and possibly timeout as well until a request succeed. After a success, the timeout does not appear for a few minutes.